# High performance selectable cells in large table - IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, html-table

I am working on an application with a firm business requirement to display an html table with up to 60 rows and up to 50 columns.

Ideally, users would be able to select individual table cells, or click and drag to select multiple cells.

My problem is that I'm limited to using IE6 at the moment, and I have been having real trouble finding (or coding) a way to allow for this kind of selection on this many cells without severe performance degradation.

My current method looks basically like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selecting = false;
    var colStart, rowStart;

    var tableContainer = $("#tableContainer")

    tableContainer.delegate("td", "mousedown", function() {
        //Clear Selection
        tableContainer.find("td.selected").removeClass("selected");

        $(this).addClass("selected");
        colStart = $(this).index();
        rowStart = $(this).parents("tr").index();
        selecting = true;
    }).delegate("td", "mouseover", function() {
        if (selecting) {
            //Clear Selection
            tableContainer.find("td.selected").removeClass("selected");

            var theCell = $(this);

            // Get the row and column numbers of the current cell 
            var colEnd = theCell.index();
            var rowEnd = theCell.parents("tr").index();

            // Account for rowEnd being smaller than rowStart
            var rowSliceStart = Math.min(rowStart, rowEnd);
            var rowSliceEnd = Math.max(rowStart, rowEnd);

            tableContainer.find("tr").slice(rowSliceStart, rowSliceEnd + 1).each(function() {
                var colSliceStart = Math.min(colStart, colEnd);
                var colSliceEnd = Math.max(colStart, colEnd);

                // Add the required class to the children
                $(this).children().slice(colSliceStart, colSliceEnd + 1).addClass("selected");
            });
        }
    }).delegate("td", "mouseup", function() {
        selecting = false;
    });
});​
```

Does anybody have any suggestions for a method to improve the performance of this function?  I believe the adding/removing of classes is taking up most of the performance overhead, so I'm especially hoping to find efficiencies there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Tables are the overhead themselves, especially when they contain lots of stuff. Tables also render only when they are complete. Consider paginations if possible.
2. Constant DOM manipulations, repaints (change appearance) and reflows (change in dimensions) is also an overhead.
3. IE6 itself wasn't built to do heavy JS operations. IE6 is what? 10 years old? What was JS 10 years ago? validations and pop-ups right?
4. Repeated function calls. in jQuery, it's best to cache the value of function calls like the `$(this)` instead of calling it repeatedly.
5. As what I understand in your code, you are running `$.each()`, slice and some random math during mouseover. That's heavy.
6. consider using a newer jQuery

Also, I have cleaned a bit of your code:

```
$(function() {
    var selecting = false,
        tableContainer = $("#tableContainer"),
        colStart, rowStart;

    tableContainer.on("mousedown", 'td', function() {
        var $this = $(this); //reference this
        colStart = $this.index();
        rowStart = $this.closest("tr").index(); //use closest instead of parents to avoid going up to root
        $(".selected", tableContainer).removeClass("selected"); //context instead of find
        $this.addClass("selected");

        selecting = true;
    }).on("mouseover", 'td', function() {
        if (selecting) {

            var theCell = $(this),
                colEnd = theCell.index(),
                rowEnd = theCell.closest("tr").index(), //use closest
                rowSliceStart = Math.min(rowStart, rowEnd),
                rowSliceEnd = Math.max(rowStart, rowEnd);

            $(".selected", tableContainer).removeClass("selected");

            $("tr", tableContainer).slice(rowSliceStart, rowSliceEnd + 1).each(function() {
                var colSliceStart = Math.min(colStart, colEnd),
                    colSliceEnd = Math.max(colStart, colEnd);
                $('> *', this).slice(colSliceStart, colSliceEnd + 1).addClass("selected"); //using selector to get children instead of $(this).children()
            });
        }
    }).on("mouseup", 'td', function() {
        selecting = false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: Nice. Could also maybe cache the list of selected cells to avoid having to find them again between each mouseover handler calls..?

Comment: Could also keep a cache of `$("tr", tableContainer)`

Comment: @Ben yes, you could cache (it's tricky though), but it's up to the OP to build one. But there is an issue of garbage collection. If elements get removed in the DOM, the cache entry corresponding to that element must also be manually nulled. Or else, memory leaks occur.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  Unfortunately IE6 is out of my control and pagination isn't an option.  I think the math is essentially free in terms of performance overhead, and the slice method is the fastest way I could think of to get the selected subset of rows/columns for highlighting.  I will have a look at the docs for the jQuery selectors (and contexts) you have used in the cleaned up code.  Some valuable info in there on improving my selecting techniques :-)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't actually look too bad. The only thing I could think of off the top of my head would be to calculate just the deltas on mouseover. That is, store the previous start and end columns/rows and on the next mouseover event, update the classes of just the elements which have changed.

Other minor things:

- cache `$(this)` in the mousedown handler
- I'm not 100% sure about this one for IE6, but you could try changing the selector from `.find('td.selected')` to just `.find('.selected')`. The first has two conditions to check, vs just one. In modern browsers, the second would *definitely* be faster, since jQuery can leverage `getElementsByClassName`, but that doesn't exist in IE6, so who knows?

  - You could also experiment with making a more targetted selector, especially if the contents of the cells contain further DOM elements. `.find('> tr > .selected')`
- throttle the mouseover handler.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I will have a think about how to approach deltas, as the addClass() method definitely has the most performance overhead, so if I can cut down the number of elements I'm working on it should help.  Could I just ask what you mean by throttling the mouseover handler?  Something like setting a timeout so it is more like a hover?  If so, do you have any examples of how it might work?

Comment: @Alex Here's a jQ plugin for throttling functions: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ It simply means that the function won't be executed every time there's a mouseover, but at most, once per X milliseconds.